# In React jsonschema form(rjsf-team) version 5. Reset custom ui:widget on submit button

Tags: jsonschema

I am new to React jsonschema form(rjsf-team) version 5, I have created a uiSchema with UI:widget with custom input template. Can any one help me to reset the value of the form on submit.

Thanks in advance